# Background color not applying after shifting applied in material bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have 6 items in my navigator. I have put shifting={false} because I want to display all the labels. But now the specific background color for each tab is not applying. Is there a way to have all the labels and also the specific background colors?